# DXA 1.4 JAVA Get Id Keyword

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

The class Tag has the following fields:

```
@JsonProperty("DisplayText")
private String displayText;

@JsonProperty("Key")
private String key;

@JsonProperty("TagCategory")
private String tagCategory;
```

But we need also the keyword id. I was adding this mapping but it's not working.

```
@JsonProperty("Id")
private String id;
```

We thought that with new versions of DXA and DD4T, all JSON  fields will be mapped and its in the TBB where we decide what we want to filter. Furthermore, what about metadata in keywords? Do we have to query the broker?

Comment: The missing keyword metadata is identified as an issue already, see https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/30